# How can I delay an animation without using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()

Tags: c#, animation, sleep

I want to move my text up, but if I use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()` my app gets stuck. I think that the using a `Timer` is a good way to solve it but pls show me how. I was trying to use `Animate()` also, but I didn't solve it by this way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i+=2)
{
    Brush snizovaniViditelnosti = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0+i*8, 0+i*8,0+i*8));
    g.DrawString("+1", fontPridaniMaterialu, snizovaniViditelnosti, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y - i);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
    //ImageAnimator.Animate()
    Timer d = new Timer();
    d.Interval = 55;
    Refresh();
}
```

It's suppose to work that I click on some button and then appears text - "+1" and it will be moving up with reducing opacity. Finally it will disappear.

Comment: use `await Task.Delay(msec)`

Comment: You likely need to give the timer a callback or something. There are almost surely tutorials that cover this topic. Have you done any research?

Comment: @L.B: if he does not understand how to use timer, await will be a complete magic for him.

Comment: what UI tech are you using? WinForms, WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a `Timer` out of your `for` loop and replace the loop by a `Tick` event. At the moment you are re-creating the `Timer` in every loop iteration. Put it as a component to your control, like this:

```
// Timer Interval is set to 0,5 second
private Timer _timer = new Timer { Interval = 500 };
```

And adding also the following fields to your control for

```
private int _index = 0;
private int _maxIndex = 30;
```

After this adding a `delegate` to the `Tick` event, which will moving up your text a ttle bit on every tick.

```
this._timer.Tick += delegate
{
    if (this._index < this._maxIndex)
    {
        var alphaValue = 255 - this._index * 8;

        Brush snizovaniViditelnosti = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alphaValue, 255, 255, 255));
        g.DrawString("+1", fontPridaniMaterialu, snizovaniViditelnosti, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y - this._index);
        Refresh();

        this._index++;
    }
    else
    {
        this._timer.Stop();
    }
};
```

If you only want to reduce opacity, reduce the `alpha` value and leave the color - as shown in the example above.

And wire this to your `Button` click event

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._timer.Start();
}
```

---

*Hint: This is a quick solution for only one item. If you want to do this for more than one item you may add a class to your code containing the text, the `Timer` and the current and maxIndex.*

---

I guess you are using `winforms`.
To avoid flickering while re-drawing your UI. You should activate [double buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls).
See more information about [Handling and Raising Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)

---

As [@apocalypse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6552578/apocalypse) suggested in his answer. It will be better to setup a fix start location for your text to move up.

Answer (score 0):

Grab `Timer` and `Button` from toolbox.

Then select `timer` and go to `events` section in `properties window`. Double click `Tick` event. Apply your logic for moving text.

For button you need to use `click` event.

Sample code:

```
private void timer1_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Location = new Point (button1.Location.X + 1, button1.Location.Y);
}

private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start ();
}
```